# module named 'app' already exists on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-module

I did something wrong and I don't know what I did. But the module name has been changed to `my-android-app`.

And I am trying to get it back to `app`. The default name of single module.

I tried `Rename Module`. But I get.

[image]

in the drop down menu of build, there are `my-android-app` and `app`. But I just have one build.gradle of module from `my-android-app`.

In the project structure. I just have `my-android-app`. Nothing to delete.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: take a backup of existing project, now Project Structure dialog can be accessed from "File -> Project Structure" or by right click on a Module and selecting "Module Settings". there select the delete (-) option, now it will not be treated as module

Comment: @SHASHISHEKHARBarnwal I just have `my-android-app` in the project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to rename `*.iml` file(IntelliJ IDEA Module). This is the name of module. This file describes about the module.
2. Edit configuration if you see two.

[image]

3. Delete all except for `app`. And change `Name` to `app` if its name is different.

[image]

4. `.idea >`your-app.iml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/your-app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/your-app.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

5. Delete one of them. (Maybe `your-app.iml` module tags.) Or if the location is incorrect then fix it.
6. File > Invalidate Caches & Restart.
7. Clean Build.